# Unable to connect to an ibmnode:latest-based container with putty over ssh

Tags: ssh, docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I am unable to connect to a container in created. Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode:latest

COPY id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/
RUN cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install git && mkdir /vApp

COPY . vApp
RUN cd vApp && npm install -d --production

EXPOSE 3000 22
CMD ["node", "vApp/app.js"]
```

Here is the output of ice ps:

```
Container Id                         Name                   Group      Image                          Created      State    Private IP      Public IP       Ports

bbf72b72-6377-4c53-afdf-a133eed1872c toto                                                             May 28 17:31 Running  172.31.0.9      129.41.226.101  [3000, 22]
```

But impossible to SSH to the container.
I can ping the container, but the connection is refused on port 22.

Thanks

Comment: I thought it could be because the ibmnode:latest image I am using in the FROM is not SSH ready. The ibmliberty:latest is SSH ready, as described in the Containers docs in the Bluemix console, but is the ibmnode too ?

Comment: if you just want to get into the container `docker exec -it bbf7 bash` or a similar command will get you a shell inside the container, see the doc https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec

Comment: Not what I am trying to achieve. I have a external server that needs to connect to port 22 to do some stuff on the container as it runs.

Comment: In addition, I don't believe docker exec works with containers running in Bluemix. Does it ?

Comment: If it is a docker container, it should always be possible to connect inside using `docker exec` . I have looked at various  bluemix containers at https://registry.hub.docker.com/search?q=bluemix&searchfield= I see nothing that would prevent using `docker exec` and while you are inside a container, check the port 22, if SSH is installed, if not install it

Answer (score 1):

While the `ibmnode` image does have a ssh server installed, you have overridden the `CMD` entry in your `Dockerfile` to only start the Node.js application, which means that the `sshd` daemon is not running when you run your container.  Note that if you `docker inspect` the **ibmnode** image you will find the current `Cmd` setting as:

```
"Cmd": [
    "/usr/bin/supervisord",
    "-n"
],
```

While it is strongly recommended to use `docker exec` to access containers, at this time the Bluemix Container service does not enable `docker exec` access to containers, so you are going to be stuck with solutions like using a supervisor to start both the ssh daemon and your Node.js application.  This is trivially copied from others who have done the same, but reveals another reason why the core design of Docker is one process per container as it simplifies the container configuration and `CMD`/`ENTRYPOINT` setup.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using *supervisord* to set up ssh access for my containers.

In my Dockerfile I do
    RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
    ADD sshd.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/sshd.conf

```
ADD id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
RUN cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

# the line below is needed for SSH to work with ubuntu 14.04
RUN sed -i 's/session \+required \+pam_loginuid\.so/session optional pam_loginuid.so/' /etc/pam.d/sshd

EXPOSE 22
```

My sshd.conf reads

```
[program:sshd]
command=/usr/sbin/sshd -D
```